How Can I do deeplink here?
I have one web app app.events6.com and React native app as well, I want to implement deeplink but its not working when from third party app clicking this link app.events.com/services/view/33 it is opnenig from browser evrytime instead of app.
I tried everyhing like modifying the android's manifest.xml file hosting assetlink.json file but still not working
here is the code manifest
  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="app.events6.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/services/view/" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

here is the code for deeplink
import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

const ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME = 'com.biz.event6';
const IOS_BUNDLE_ID = 'com.biz.event6';
const APPLE_STORE_ID = '15232262224';

const config = {
  screens: {
    splashScreen: 'splash',
    home: 'home',
    packageDetail: 'packages/details/:packageId',
    eventServiceDetail: 'services/view/:serviceId',
   // MessagesScreen: 'MessagesScreen',
  },
};

const linking = {
  prefixes: ['app.events6.com/','events6'],

  async getInitialURL() {
    try {
      const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      const dynamicLinkUrl = await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink();

      if (dynamicLinkUrl) {
        return dynamicLinkUrl.url;
      }

      if (url != null) {
        return url;
      }

      return 'events6://splash';
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error getting initial URL:', error);
    }
  },
  subscribe(listener) {
    const onReceiveURL = ({ url }) => {
      listener(url);
    };
    Linking.addEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
    const handleDynamicLink = (dynamicLink) => {
      listener(dynamicLink.url);
    };
    const unsubscribeToDynamicLinks = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLink);

    return () => {
      unsubscribeToDynamicLinks();
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
    };
  },
  config,
};

async function fireBuildLink(url, param = null) {
  let link;
  if (param) {
    link = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink({
      domainUriPrefix: 'https://events.page.link',
      link: `https://www.events6.com/share/${url}/${param}`,
      android: { packageName: ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME },
      ios: {
        bundleId: IOS_BUNDLE_ID,
        appStoreId: APPLE_STORE_ID,
      },
      navigation: {
        forcedRedirectEnabled: true,
      },
    });
  } else {
    link = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink({
      domainUriPrefix: 'https://events.page.link',
      link: `https://www.events6.com/share/${url}`,
      android: { packageName: ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME },
      ios: {
        bundleId: IOS_BUNDLE_ID,
        appStoreId: APPLE_STORE_ID,
      },
      navigation: {
        forcedRedirectEnabled: true,
      },
    });
  }

  return link;
}

export { fireBuildLink, linking };


Tried:-
Modifying the manifest.xml file various way
Hostel assetlinks file at .wellknwon folder
tried to change code in deeplink.js file
Expected:- App should be open when user clicking a link from third party app
